# How to solve the jquery conflict. when i add autocomplete jquery plugins other jquery plugins do not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
 <script src="http://test.com/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4"></script>

 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

When i add the jquery auto complete. The jquery slider is not working. The wordpress theme use jquery.js ver=1.12.4. and the autocomplete plugins use jquery-1.11.2.min.js.  when i add the autocomplete, auto complete working but slider is not working.

I need both plugins to work.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you really sure they need separate versions? Does it not work if you only include 1.12.4?

Answer (score 3):

See code below,
Use any variable to replace $.And, generally, you want to do this right after including jQuery and any plugins: Example:

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
    jq("button").click(function(){
        jq("p").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: yes i solved the problem. I moved the jquery library of autocomplete on header.php and it solved problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

yes i solved the problem. I moved the jquery library of autocomplete on header.php and it solved problem. Thank you